# How to modify the rows of a DataTable using the array values in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

```
  function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        
        data.addColumn('string', 'From');
        data.addColumn('string', 'To');
        data.addColumn('number', 'number of calls');
        data.addRows([
          [ 'calls', 'X', 5 ],
          [ 'calls', 'A', 7 ],
          [ 'calls', 'B', 6 ],
          [ 'calls', 'C', 2 ],
          [ 'calls', 'D', 9 ],
          [ 'calls', 'E', 4 ]
        ]);
```

The above is just a portion of an HTML code that I would like to modify the `data.addRows([])` by using the array values. It seems not practical to hardcode the rows, so I believe there is a simple workaround for this. For example I have a range values in google sheet, `var values=Spreadsheet.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1').getRange("A1:C6")`. I tried to use `data.addRows(values)` but its not working. I am new to apps script coding and I don't know where to insert my code `var values=Spreadsheet.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1').getRange("A1:D5")` to be usable in that HTML code above dataTable. Please help.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve and what problem you have.

Comment: Thank you for the response @gru . I want to modify the adding of rows in the dataTable. Is it possible to use array values instead of hardcoding each single rows? I would like to replace those ['calls','x',5],['calls','A',7],,ect,,, by an array values coming from getRange().getValues method of google apps scipt.

Comment: `var values=Spreadsheet.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1').getRange("A1:C6")` is a Range you need to `var values=Spreadsheet.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1').getRange("A1:C6").getValues()` to get the Array of values

Comment: Yeah, I know that "values" above is the array, how can I use those values in adding them in a row of dataTable instead of hardcoding them with ['calls','x',5],etc..? I tried data.addRows(values); but its not working. I also tried to loop them and reduce it to data.addRow(values[i]) still not working.

Comment: Actually, the code is coming from: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey I want to modify the adding of rows since I know how to get the values by array method. I don't want to hardcode those adding of rows. Please help.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (it should include server-side and client-side code)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
var values=Spreadsheet.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1').getRange("A1:D5").getValues();

data.addRows(values);
```

Comment: It says: "VM59:8 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Spreadsheet is not defined
    at drawChart (<anonymous>:8:20)" @Cooper

Comment: So what do you wish me to do about it? I don't even have a complete reproducible function.  I have no idea what the data is and I've never seen the spreadsheet.  You have all of those things so the ball is in your court